# How the loop is break if it get negative number from an array?

Tags: node.js

here is an array like

```
   const arr = [1, 2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

now I want to read the all element from this array by for looping. but when the element reach to **-4**, then the loop will break automatically. how can I do it by for looping?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also use for-of loop with a break statement.

```
    for (let item of arr){
       if (item === -4)
          break;

       console.log(item)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
for(i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
   if(arr[i] === -4){
       break;
   }
   // otherwise your code goes here
}
```